# "how to prove this function is one to one "

Tags: number-theory, functions

Let $f(i,k)=(2^i)(3^k)$ where $i,k$ are natural numbers.

Show that $f$ is one to one.
I have tried to solve it.
Please, can you help me solve it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $f(i, k) = f(j, l)$, then you have

$$2^i \cdot 3^k = 2^j \cdot 3^l$$

Rearranging gives

$$2^{i - j} = 3^{l - k}$$

What conditions on $i$, $j$, $l$, and $k$ allow for this to happen?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can give an elementary proof as shown by *T. Bongers* hint or use the [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Comment: A link to the key idea! +1

Answer (score 1):

If $f(i_1,k_1)=f(i_2,k_2)$

we have $$2^{i_1}3^{k_1}=2^{i_2}3^{k_2}\implies 2^{i_1-i_2}=3^{k_2-k_1}$$

Now as $(2,3)=1$ each must be $1$